# Reintegrate "added" folders

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn

The scenario is the following:

- trunk is branched to A
- trunk is added directly folder1 with files file1 and file2
- A reintegrates trunk

The result is that when committing the merged working directory into A, its status is that:

folder1 *added*
folder1/file1 *not to be seen, marked as up to date with repository*
folder1/file2 *not to be seen, marked as up to date with repository*

So the commit ends up adding folder1 to the branch, but it doesn't add the files.
So they remain in the working directory as under version control, but they're not...

My workaround is, after this commit:

- move out this "added" folders
- commit the delete
- move back the folders
- commit

As this doesn't quite often it's doable, but it is far from a decent solution, so I think I'm definitely missing something...

I've tried all sorts of cleanup and nothing marks those new files as "added" (to be committed)...

Comment: What specific command (actual svn command, as typed) did you use to "reintegrates trunk" on branch A? A "reintegrate merge" is the WRONG merge to do here, if that's what you did.

Comment: I'm thinking it was not the proper merge type indeed, specially as it says in the usage description "reintegrate back to trunk". But I am using TortoiseSVN and there are 2 other options (merge range of revision and merge 2 diff trees) and both required specifying a range of revisions when I basically want "since branching revision up to trunk HEAD".. Re-integrate seemed to do that. Should I use range of revisions and manually check the "branching revision number"? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next time you want to merge in some changes from trunk to get your working copy up-to-date, if you select "range of revisions"  but then leave the range empty it will usually do the right thing for you. Or you can pick multiple revisions in a "show log" dialog corresponding to all the revisions since your branch if you prefer.

To fix your current situation, I think you've (in effect) made trunk into a re-integrated and therefore "dead" branch. Luckily there are ways to fix the branch to keep it "alive" after you've done a reintegrate merge. In your case you'll need to apply them in reverse since your trunk is the "dead" branch. See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge.advanced.reintegratetwice for details.